# Formatação de exibição de Data DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

tenho um campo no banco de dados, DataHora, e queria exibir na tela para o usuário, mas em campos separados, sendo Data e Hora.

Primeiro exibe a Data

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataHora)
```

Segundo exibe a Hora

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataHora)
```

Já tentei formatar usando o código a baixo, mas não deu resultado algum...

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataHora, {0:dd/MM/yyyy})
```

Sujestões?

Comment: Eu prefiro utilizar um view model e tratar isso em propriedades diferentes. Exemplo:         public class MyModel
        {
            public DateTime DataHora { get; set; }

            public string Data
            {
                get { return DataHora.ToShortDateString(); }
            }

            public string Hora { get { return DataHora.ToShortTimeString(); } }
        }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Html.DisplayFor()` não serve para separação de data e hora como você quer. O método atende bem apenas para o uso integral de informação da variável.

Use, ao invés disso:

```
@item.DataHora.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

e

```
@item.DataHora.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: tiro o @Html.DisplayFor(...) e coloco apenas o @item.DataHora.Tostring... ?

Comment: Agradeço mais uma vez. Deu certinho aqui

Comment: Exatamente. O `DisplayFor` possui várias utilidades, mas apenas com variáveis em sua integralidade.

Answer (score 0):

Eu prefiro tratar isso em view model, exemplo:

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public DateTime? DataHora { get; set; }

        public string Data
        {
            get { return DataHora?.ToShortDateString(); }
        }

        public string Hora { get { return DataHora?.ToShortTimeString(); } }
    }
```