# Tratamento de uma string na view - asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma `public string TimeUpdate { get; set; }` no meu model que é da forma `"13-12-2016 17:12:09"`.Preciso que na view ela apareça apenas as horas e os minutos, como eu posso fazer o tratamento do campo?

PS: Já tentei `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:t}")]` mas sem sucesso. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez será que isso é duplicata se o campo é `String` e lá o campo é um `DateTime`, existe diferenças, não existe nessa conversão?

Comment: Bom, `[DisplayFormat]` não funciona neste caso. Ele deve ter convertido um `DateTime` padrão para `string` se for em *Model*. Posso até votar para reabrir.

Comment: A minha preocupação foi em relação ser ou não duplicata, porque, os dados são diferentes e para `DateTime` seria uma duplicata, mas, para `String` não, pela conversão. @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Tudo bem. Está reaberta. Não vou responder. Apenas colocar o link da resposta que dei na outra: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162550/formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-exibi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-data-displayfor?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Mario porque você usa assim: `public string TimeUpdate { get; set; }` ??? você fez algum código adicional?

Comment: Não quis explicar como eu obtenho essa informação para não prolongar a questão, mas é o seguinte: Esse é um model de uma requisição REST e no Json retornado é um campo do tipo ´"timeUpdate": "14-12-2016 10:15:34"´. Já tentei trocar o tipo para DateTime só que eu obtenho `01/01/0001 00:00:00` daí não sei como tratar isso... =/

Comment: @Mário o seu problema então é antes dessa pergunta, que é transformar um `JSON` em um objeto. Se eu fosse você criaria uma nova pergunta de como receber um `REST` que possui uma data nesse formato "13-12-2016 17:12:09" com [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) e depois utilizar a solução feita pelo Cigano nesse [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162550/formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-exibi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-data-displayfor?noredirect=1&lq=1) seria melhor, porque, eu até poderia propor uma solução nessa classe mas, poderia ser considerado uma gambiarra